# Replacing all integers in a string

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, fortran

Let's say I have some expression like,

```
expr = 1*a + 2*b +3*c + 4*d
```

I want to write this to a string that I can then use in some other Fortran script. I want all the integers to be of the form "X.0_dp". To do this I can simply do,

```
StringReplace[
  ToString[expr, FortranForm], {"1" -> "2.0_dp", "2" -> "2.0_dp", 
  "3" -> "3.0_dp", "4" -> "4.0_dp"}]
```

which works a treat.

Now, is there a way such that I don't have to do this by hand, and generalizes to all integers? e.g. something of the form,

```
StringReplace[
  ToString[expr, FortranForm], {"x" -> "x.0_dp"}]
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Does `StringReplace[ToString[expr, FortranForm], x : NumberString :> If[StringFreeQ[x, "."], x <> ".0_dp", x <> "0_dp"]]` suit your needs?

Comment: Yes that works perfectly! If you submit as an answer I can then mark as accepted :) Further:is there a way to do this for decimals e.g. 0.5 ---> 0.50_dp ?

Comment: Did you try the snippet I gave in that case?

Comment: Ah my bad - all works. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want all integers to be formatted in the same way, you can override the [`FortranForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FortranForm) formatting of [`Integer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integer):

```
Unprotect[Integer];
Format[i_Integer, FortranForm] := Format[
    ToString @ i <> ".0_dp",
    OutputForm
]
Protect[Integer];
```

Then:

```
ToString[1*a + 2*b +3*c + 4*d, FortranForm]
```

> ```
> "a + 2.0_dp*b + 3.0_dp*c + 4.0_dp*d"
> ```

If you want to retain the 1 before the `a`, just use HoldForm to prevent evaluation:

```
ToString[HoldForm[1*a + 2*b +3*c + 4*d], FortranForm]
```

> ```
> "1.0_dp*a + 2.0_dp*b + 3.0_dp*c + 4.0_dp*d"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ToString[(expr /. 
    Times[x_Integer, y_Symbol] :> 
     ToString[x, FortranForm] <> ".0_dp " <> 
      ToString[y, FortranForm]) /. a :> "1.0_dp a"]

(* "1.0_dp a + 2.0_dp b + 3.0_dp c + 4.0_dp d"  *)
```

Have fun!